# Вывод текста в терминал при выполнении os.popen().read()

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

При выполнении команды `os.popen('iwconfig').read()`, информация не касающаяся wlan0 отображается в терминале, хотя должна идти в переменную без всякого вывода в терминал, в чем может быть причина?[image: прилагаю картинку]

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос есть на английском so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339469/reading-a-os-popencommand-into-a-string

Там предлагают такой вариант:

```
import os

process = os.popen('iwconfig')
preprocessed = process.read()
process.close()
```

Альтернативно предлагается пробовать `subprocess.Popen`, т.к. `os.popen()` объявлено нежелательным с python 2.6

Answer (score 0):

`os.popen()` перенаправляет только стандартный вывод (`stdout`).

Вы можете видеть вывод из потока ошибок (`stderr`) или команда может писать в терминал напрямую в обход стандартных потоков.

Чтобы перехватить оба потока дочернего процесса:

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_output

output = check_output('iwconfig', stderr=STDOUT)
```

Чтобы перехватить [прямой  вывод](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20981435/4279) в терминал, [можно script утилиту использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/718862/23044). Пример:

```
import os

cmd = r'''python -c "import os; os.write(os.open('/dev/tty', os.O_WRONLY|os.O_NOCTTY), b'abc\n')"'''
output = check_output(['script', '-e', '-q', '-c', cmd, os.devnull])
```