# Python subprocess.call запретить вывод в терминал результата

Tags: python, linux, python-2.x, subprocess

Приветствую всех, есть функция на Python 2.x, которая пингует хост через определенный сетевой интерфейс через вызов fping в Linux. Сама функция работает, только кидает в терминал строку c результатом выполнения:

```
8.8.8.8 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 5/5/0%, min/avg/max = 50.5/50.5/50.5
```

Возможно ли как-то запретить вывод этой строки в терминале?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#-------------------------------------------
import os            
import subprocess

def Host_Ping( iface, host ):
    response = subprocess.call(["fping", "-c 5", "-p 2", "-t200", host, "-I", iface], stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
    if response == 0:
        result = True           # ping ok 
    else:
        result = False          # ping error
    return result


print Host_Ping ('eth1', "8.8.8.8")
```

Comment: в сторону: (не имеет отношения к самому вопросу) 1- если вы хотите эмулировать `cmd -opt value` команду, то следует каждый аргумент отдельно помещать: `rc = call(['cmd', '-opt', 'value'])` 2- сами значения параметров для fping возможно не верны (`-p` порядка ~1000 обычно) 3- зависит от задачи, но вы вероятно хотите больше одно хоста за раз передавать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы убрать вывод команды:

1. Используйте опции самой команды. К примеру, `-q` (не поможет для fping).
2. Если команда пишет в stdout, stderr перенаправьте в `/dev/null`:

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python2
   import os
   import subprocess

   DEVNULL = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_WRONLY)        
   rc = subprocess.call(["echo", "dropped"], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
   ```

   `subprocess.DEVNULL` встроен на Python 3.
3. Если команда пишет напрямую в терминал, то можно [`script(1)` утилиту](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) использовать, чтобы перехватить вывод:

   ```
   cmd = r"""python -c 'import os; os.write(os.open(os.ctermid(), os.O_WRONLY), b"abc\n")'"""
   rc = subprocess.call(['script', '-e', '-q', '-c', cmd, os.devnull],
                        stdout=DEVNULL)
   ```